# Network synthesis. What kind of knowledge do I need to solve this question?

Tags: passive-networks, homework

Below is my homework assignment related to network synthesis. I have never seen this type of question before and no idea how to start the solution. Can somebody give me some kind of hint to start it off?

---

> An LC network is to be designed to meet the following specifications:
> a. It is to have infinite impedance at 1200 Hz and at 5000 Hz.
> b. It is to have zero impedance at 2400 Hz.
> c. It is to have reactance of 100 ohms at 3000 Hz.
> i. Determine the impedance function from these specifications.
> ii. Find the four canonical network realizations, including element values.
> iii. Select the network you consider to be the best network from an engineering point of view, considering element size, cost and other practical matters

[image: image of original question]

Comment: arushi jaiswal - Hi, I see you have edited your question and I have copied your explanation from the "edit reason" into the question itself. Since you are now not asking for answers to your homework questions, but instead asking for ideas how to approach the question, I'll reopen the question and give site members a chance to respond to the updated question.